# How to convert app.js file into a component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Hello for testing purposes I want to convert my app.js file into a component so I can render it in a different file that will be my new app.js. How would I convert this code to a component in react?

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LoadingScreen from './LoadingScreen';
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './RegisterScreen';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';



var firebaseConfig = {
    //
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen
})

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    Login: LoginScreen,
    Register: RegisterScreen
})

export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            Loading: LoadingScreen,
            App: AppStack,
            Auth: AuthStack
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: "Loading"
        }

    )
)
```

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. You already have a default export, so you can just import it as you would any other default exported element right?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            Loading: LoadingScreen,
            App: AppStack,
            Auth: AuthStack
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: "Loading"
        }

    )
)

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer/>
    );
  }
}
```